# opencart 4 Multi language Remove ?language= from Url

Tags: php, url, seo, opencart

Hello Im trying to remove ?language= from my url in opencart 4

the exmpale is i Want the url change from this

```
exmpale.com/en?language=en-gb
exmpale.com/fr?language=fr
```

To

```
exmpale.com/en
```

First Step I added This code To (catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php)

```
if($data['route'] === 'common/home') {
   if($data['language'] === 'fr' && $key ==='language') {
      $url = '/';
      unset($data[$key]);
   } elseif($data['language'] === 'en-gb' && $key ==='language') {
      $url = '/en';
      unset($data[$key]);
  }
}
```

that change worked and removed the ?language= from url but the route is giving me not found error

Answer (score 1):

edited: oh, sorry, i simply misunderstoor your queestion.
you have to use few keys in oc_seo_url table:

```
language_id = 1 (let's say you have en-gb as ID 1)
key = language
value = en-gb
keyword = en
sort_order = -2

language_id = 2 (lets say fr have ID 2)
key = language
value = en-gb
keyword = en
sort_order = -2

language_id = 1
key = language
value = fr 
keyword = fr
sort_order = -2

language_id = 1
key = language
value = fr 
keyword = en
sort_order = -2
```

P.S.
In my case i added next code to remove main language from url at all

```
                if (empty($this->request->get['language'])) {
                    $this->request->get['language']='uk-ua';
                }
```

after `foreach ($parts as $part) {...}` (~line #20 in orig file)
in catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php

seo url for that language is set to empty string in database.

P.S. and don't forget to modify rewrite function in same file like this.
replace

```
        foreach ($paths as $result) {
            $url .= '/' . $result['keyword'];
        }
```

with

```
foreach ($paths as $result) {
            if (!empty($result['keyword'])) {

                $url .= '/' . $result['keyword'];
            } else {
                $url .= $result['keyword'];

            }
        }
```